# Updating subject line to `{{{subject}}}` in Sendgrid not working

Tags: python-3.x, email, twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I am trying to make a call to SendGrid via the Python SDK:

```py
self._sendgrid.client.templates._(template_id).versions._(version_id).patch(request_body=data)
```

where the data is:

```py
{"name": "this is a name1234.12341234132", "subject": "{{{subject}}}"}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```py
{'error': 'Cannot update the active version with warnings.', 'warnings': [{'message': 'Failed to validate handlebars'}]}
```

My goal is to get the `subject` value updated to use `{{{subject}}}` as the value, so that we can dynamically set the Subject of the emails based on whatever is calling our function to send the template. I can do this, by manually setting the template versions within SendGrid directly, but trying to use the SDK or API, I am unable to do this. We have a lot of templates and it would take a while to update them all manually. Looking for help.

Solution to the problem I am experiencing when using the Python SDK for SendGrid.

Comment: Handlebars does use `{{x}}` not `{{{x}}}`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.